# Can any KitchenAid stand mixer attachments be used to make peanut butter?

Tags: equipment, stand-mixer, nut-butters

Can I use any of the various attachments for my Kitchenaid stand mixer to make peanut butter? I was thinking one of the different grinding attachments might work, insofar as the machine at my local merchant looks like a hopper full of peanuts and a grinder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only one that could feasibly handle it would be the grinder. However, in the manual http://www.kitchenaid.com/assets/pdfs/product/ZUSECARE/FGA_Use%20and%20Care_EN.pdf on page 5 it states "Note: Very hard, dense foods such as totally dried homemade bread should not be ground in the Food Grinder. Homemade bread should be ground fresh and then oven or air-dried." If dried, dense bread is too much for the grinder then peanuts would definitely be to much as well. My recommendation is to use a food processor.

Comment: A blender would also work.

Comment: It's quite possible to strip the worm gear in the stand mixer's power train if you don't heed the warning about not working the thing too hard. Fortunately it's a pretty easy fix, and cheap replacement parts are available online.

Comment: I dunno, I don't think nuts are harder than totally dry homemade bread-- that stuff is more like a rock than food.  I bought the meat grinder attachment for my Kitchenaid specifically to grind walnuts with (for nut rolls at Christmas) and haven't had any issues yet.  It'll do two pounds in about five minutes, no problem.

Answer (score 11):

## KitchenAid meat grinder

WOO HOO!The answer is yes. Having read a number of homemade peanut butter posts, and coming to the conclusion that no one was brave enough to take a chance ruining their mixer or attachment, I took it on myself to try it with the meat grinder.

I used the small plate.  What came out in just seconds, looked like spaghetti. On closer inspection it is just smooth, slightly grainy peanut butter.  No strain on the mixer.  I ran it through a second time. It came out with a sheen that indicated the nut oils were being pressed out of the nuts in the process.

I have used food processors. The drawback is that even the heavy duty food processors will burn out if you do it too often.  It also takes a while to do it this way, and can be a pain to clean up.

I bought two different models of Nostalgia peanut butter machines. Both work but not optimally.

The *KitchenAid* mixer with the [meat grinder attachment](https://www.kitchenaid.com/countertop-appliances/stand-mixers/attachments/p.stand-mixer-metal-food-grinder-attachment.ksmmga.html) is a very simple and fast way to make peanut butter with no additives (just peanuts).  I'm  ready to sell my other attempts on craigslist.

Note: peanuts are actually very oily beans. They are not hard, and as the oils are extruded, the knife is lubricated.  As I stated, no strain on the mixer at all.

Comment: As a plus one, I regularly use the meat grinder in the manner you describe—except that I only run the peanuts through once—to make peanut butter. Depending on how dry the peanuts are I may add peanut oil afterward, and depending on how salty they are I may add salt. I’ve been doing this for over a decade; there’s been no indication of stress on the KitchenAid; purely observationally this is probably less stressful than using the meat grinder to grind meat.

Comment: Here's a video of someone making peanut butter with a KitchenAid stand mixer using the meat grinder attachment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQOR06Ne5vg

Answer (score 0):

About the question if Kitchen Aid has an attachment that will make peanut butter and watching the video on the Food Processor Attachment Slicer, I would safely say that Kitchen Aid does not at this time have an attachment that will make peanut butter.